# .htaccess wierd problem with rewriterule and hash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im adding new things to my ehop and I have some problems with rewriterule in htaccess.
Im using XAMPP as a local development tool, ale then send it to live serwer.

PHP generate links like this one:
https://kielkowski-szkolka.pl/reklamacja/c0892ce969fef9ccb1c1a8034b5e33dc19337b14

this on works on XAMPP but not on live serwer

This works on both
https://kielkowski-szkolka.pl/reklamacja/65f4c6c6686a2b248a7be2db104f3b13ea365d55

RewriteRule for this is (in .htaccess)

```
RewriteRule ^reklamacja/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?metoda=reklamacja_szczegoly&id=$1 [L]
```

why?I cant figure it out

Edit: error means that this rewriterule is skipped and another rule kicks in that redirects to home page

Comment: Could you please do let us know in case you are getting any error in your logs?

Comment: Error means that this rewriterule is skipped and another rule kicks in that redirects to home page

Comment: ok, how about using `RewriteRule ^reklamacja/(.*)$ index.php?metoda=reklamacja_szczegoly&id=$1 [L]`  once, haven't tested it but your used regex doesn't look correct to me. Let me know if this helps(please make sure you test these ulrs after clearing your browser cache).

Comment: oo it was the cache problem...Tested it on chrome with CTRL+F5 refresh. Tried it on  Edge and it works fine. thanks a lot. Happy new year to all :)